# What kind of syntax is this in Makefile? (A := $(B.$(C).D))

Tags: android, makefile, gnu-make

```
TARGET_DEVICE := $(PRODUCTS.$(INTERNAL_PRODUCT).PRODUCT_DEVICE)
```

It comes from the Android makefile. The using of dot(.) is confusing me, What kind of syntax is this? Any keyword related to this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special is going on here.

That's just a [computed variable name](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Computed-Names) expansion.

```
$ cat Makefile
PRODUCTS.foo.PRODUCT_DEVICE := foo-DEVICE
PRODUCTS.bar.PRODUCT_DEVICE := bar-DEVICE

INTERNAL_PRODUCT := foo
TARGET_DEVICE := $(PRODUCTS.$(INTERNAL_PRODUCT).PRODUCT_DEVICE)

$(info INTERNAL_PRODUCT is $(INTERNAL_PRODUCT))
$(info TARGET_DEVICE is $(TARGET_DEVICE))

INTERNAL_PRODUCT := bar
TARGET_DEVICE := $(PRODUCTS.$(INTERNAL_PRODUCT).PRODUCT_DEVICE)

$(info INTERNAL_PRODUCT is $(INTERNAL_PRODUCT))
$(info TARGET_DEVICE is $(TARGET_DEVICE))
$ make
INTERNAL_PRODUCT is foo
TARGET_DEVICE is foo-DEVICE
INTERNAL_PRODUCT is bar
TARGET_DEVICE is bar-DEVICE
```

Comment: I see now, PRODUCTS.foo.PRODUCT_DEVICE was defined somewhere else.  Thanks for your help.